# How to set localization in Cake PHP 3.5 at runtime?

Tags: php, cakephp, internationalization, translation, po

I try to use this:
https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html
But I think this code is not enough for working fine:

```
use Cake\I18n\I18n;
//Prior to 3.5 use I18n::locale()
I18n::setLocale('de_DE');
```

What another code should I add to the controller to work fine?

Comment: Please provide more details about what isn't working when you do this, including code examples and how the output differs from what you expect. See also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It is also important _where_ in the core you make that call. If you make it too late it is possible that it will have no effect as most locale depended functions have already been called. Is this in `bootstrap.php` ?